# How to display boundary of an area using Google maps API v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am writing an application where I need to mark the boundary of an area with certain colour, for example, if I search for "London", it should show a coloured boundary of London on the map. If I search for "UK", it should display coloured boundary of the UK. 
This works well with Google maps on the web browser such that if I search for "Essex" on Google maps, it shows a red-dotted boundary of Essex.

Is there anyway I can get this feature on my Android app using Google maps API v2?

I found a couple of links below:

[how to change the color of a particular area on Google map api v2 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808191/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-particular-area-on-google-map-api-v2-in-android)

[Is it possible to get cities polygonal boundaries like in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385377/is-it-possible-to-get-cities-polygonal-boundaries-like-in-google-maps/14385528#14385528)

It looks like I need boundary data in the form of polygon data points and use it as marker to display boundary. There are different websites which provide this polygon data but not sure how to use this data. It looks complicated, I think there has to be a simpler way to implement it.

EDIT:
Just to update on how i ended up doing it. I had to get Lat/Lng data from free boundary data providers and draw it manually using

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
            for(LatLng latLng: getLatLngList()) {
                options.add(latLng);
            }
            options.color(Color.RED);
            options.width(POLYLINE_WIDTH);
            map.addPolyline(options);
```

I had to draw London boroughs and I got boundary data from:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1WlXk5RnE3oVRtrsqnm48V75pfN66Do0nbIw2xX8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a REST API for this , works well with google maps on andriod.

UK Postal-Unit(ex. ZE1 0AE) ,Sector,District, City, and wards boundaries in GeoJson

https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/uk-boundaries-io

[image: query by uk postal]